# React-native async fetch returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am trying to put fetch functions into a separated file, so I can organise these API fetch easily. However, when I try to fetch and return the data, it gives me null or an unexpected json object. Here is part of my src:

```
//api.js
export async function LoginAPI(username, password) {
   const url = baseURL + "/login/";
   var params = {username: username, password: md5.hex_md5(password)};

   let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: JSON.stringify(params)
   });
   return await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: header,
      body: JSON.stringify(params)
   })
   .then((res) => res.text())
   .then((text) => text.length ? JSON.parse(text) : {})
    .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
    });
};
```

Here is the another file.

```
//index.js
var Login = React.createClass({
  onPress_login: function() {
  var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
  if (value) {
     result = LoginAPI(value.username, value.password);
     console.log(result);
  } else {
     this.AlertDialog.openDialog();
  }
},
render() {
   return (
 (...)
 <Button onPress={this.onPress_login}>
     <Text>Login</Text>
 </Button>
```

The fetch is working, it is communicating with the server. However, the console log returns me this at the first place

```
 Promise  _45: 0_54: null  _65: null  _81: 1  __proto__: Object
```

I am assuming that the `result` log in the console at the first place is not the await result (the actual response from server, but an object of fetch response). I tried to search out methods online but I can't find any post/blog/article saying how to do fetch as a function call.

Is there any way to do like swift, `LoginAPI(username, password, callback: {...})` please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're are making an async function and not waiting for the response, the you see that kind of console log.

Try this:

```
result = await LoginAPI(value.username, value.password);
```

Let me know if this was your problem.

Comment: oh nice hint! It works with this way.

`onPress_login: async function() {
      var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
      if (value) {
         result = await LoginAPI(value.username, value.password);`